# split one partition into two using cfdisk (will uuids on other parts stay the same?)

Tags: linux, partition, uuid, cfdisk

I currently have various linux partitions on `sda3-13`. If I delete `sda6` and create two new partitions using `cfdisk` I get `sda3-14`. I have `/home` on `sda7` and `/` on `sda11` which will then become `sda8` and `sda12` respecively while the UUIDs will stay the same. Can I reboot normally without any problems?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you are referring to the partitions throughout the system. Two key places are `/etc/fstab` and bootloader configuration. If you check these to be using UUIDs for the affected partitions (i.e. anything above `sda6`) it should be ok.

Alternatively, you could use a different partitioner - namely one that doesn't rename the partitions unless explicitly told to do so. IIRC `fdisk` is one of those. And I'm not sure whether the renumbering doesn't happen automatically when using GPT.

Comment: Yeah I am using uuids in fstab on my main install. Also references during the grub boot menu (using 'e') shows root=uuid-references. Is the "set root='(hd0,msdos11)'"-line ok? Dont know anything about GPT, its a standard kubuntu 12.04 installation. Fixing older installs that may use sdaX references (probably aren't any) is just a matter of manually mounting and updating fstab.

Comment: `set root='(hd0,msdos11)` is where it goes wrong - that is basically the same as `sda12` (for some reason `grub` numbers partitions from 0 unlike kernel which starts from 1).